# Configure & use mongodb mockup server for unit testing

Tags: mongodb, junit, mocking

I have to develop some Junit tests for Java code using a MongoDB store. Is there any framework/library which permits me initializing a mock in-memory MongoDB server?

(The idea is to test only the code itself, that means, in any machine independently on if MongoDB is installed & running).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you not just use a local MongoDB install? It's pretty lightweight...
Or.. a hosted mongo? mongohq.com for example?

Comment: that is how I do it right now (local Mongo). the problem is that it will be deployed and tested in a continous integration server, that means, the tests will regularly be tested in that machine.
Deploying a MongoDB server in this machine is not an option (besides, if a unit test uses external resources like a hosted service or a database server it will not be deterministic anymore, since those services stay out of control).

Comment: For those suggesting to connect to an existing Mongo, I believe Ruben is asking for something similar to how the H2 database can be used. It can be "embedded" into your unit tests.

Answer (score 11):

[fongo](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a MongoDB fake implementation in Java: [mongo-java-server](https://github.com/bwaldvogel/mongo-java-server) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14986179/4308)).

Comment: Great stuff. Clearly it has some limitations, but now I can run my Selenium tests with a clean database. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We're actually working on such a test system and it's quite feasible. In our approach our test framework extends the standard test case class (JUnit in our case but TestNG seems more capable) that sets up and tears down the various database dependecies with each test using the following steps :

Test Suite Setup

1) Start mongod process (we use ProcessBuilder, store Process instance)

Test Setup :

2) Run mongo with a test specific .js file to produce initial data state

Test

3) Run test

Test Teardown

4) Drop database

Test Suite Teardown

5) Stop mongod process (process.destroy())

Since starting and stopping mongod is the only time consuming thing i'd strongly suggest doing this as little as possible. Preferably once for the entire test suite. Our stuff isn't finished yet but early results are positive. I don't think many alternatives are available. No mongo mock library is available at time of writing and mongod does not have a in-memory/embedded mode.

Comment: how does this go cross platform?

Comment: there are no platform specific elements in the above other than starting the process. People generally don't have more than one OS for their test machines.

Comment: hm, our team is using win and *nix; we will be co'ing the project and running the tests on our individual machines.. do you suggest we package the mongo binary for both platforms?

Comment: @RemonvanVliet, How to start mongod by `sudo mongod` before each test by node js? How to workaround the `sudo` requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, you have to do that kind of thing yourself in your application layers. If you use Morphia you can use any mock framework with your service layers you like (since the objects are just POJOs), but there is nothing at the db/driver level to help you out.

Many people just use a local dev. mongodb instance with a set of test data since it is so fast. I know of people who load test data for each test, like copying a database with fake/test data.

Answer (score 0):

As part of your test fixture setup, drop the database and populate it with any default test data.