# Testing strategy for Go with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to get a project started in Go and MongoDb. I am stumped when trying to figure out the best way to unittest my database interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally people use database mocks, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413985/unit-testing-with-mongodb) for the same answer in Java.