# Using local JSON to mock Firebase for testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, firebase

I'm thinking about a testing strategy for an app that uses Firebase for its datastore.  While it's fine for end-to-end tests to make requests to the actual backend, it would be nice to be able to make unit tests of app logic that *don't* have to go out to Firebase.

I've been scouring the web for a way to use something like a local JSON file to mock the javascript Firebase service, but haven't found anything.  Does something like this exist?  If not, I'll write it and post it on github...

Comment: Take a look at node-tdd and the useNock flag. We use it for dynamodb testing but it will work the same for firebase: the first run automatically records the requests signatures and responses and the further executions just use that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/3e6ec8b109d76e63d7ac4046bf09ef77) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351959/how-to-mock-out-firebase-in-karma-tests-for-angular-app/45335167#45335167) for a detailed exploration of encapsulated TDD vs. using mocks for unit testing.

**Original Post**

It would be very difficult to properly mock a Firebase service, as it would be to mock most sophisticated data stores. Think of this in terms of mocking MySQL or [mocking MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413985/unit-testing-with-mongodb).

Assuming your goal is to make the local environment work offline, a quick solution might be to use a local instance. You can grab the [firebase-debug.js](http://static.firebase.com/v0/firebase-debug.js), save it locally, and call set(/* data */) to initialize it for offline ops.

Otherwise, your best approach would be to encapsulate all the Firebase activity to one class or library. Then you can mock that library rather than your Firebase events. And to quasi-unit test (these are technically not unit tests since they depend on an external service) the library itself, fall back to a local offline Firebase instance or set up a dev database and copy your production data (or some seed data) there.

Comment: I get you about the difficulty of mocking datastores, but I think it's sometimes worth it. I could imagine, for example, wanting to (sorta-)unit test the app-level response to a particular firebase change event, where having an easily controllable mock would be nice.  In my current case, though, your offline solution is exactly what I need. Thanks for that!

Comment: Can you explain the offline solution? I'm trying to test my app that uses Firebase and can't figure out how to mock the data coming back.

Comment: There is now a mock available. It isn't ideal as it requires that you have a solid understanding of Firebase's inner workings (e.g. local caching, synchronous local events, et al) to create sophisticated tests, but it's a pretty good starting point:  https://github.com/katowulf/mockfirebase