# How to test a service that interacts with Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

It seems like the convention for grabbing data from Firebase is to create a service class that uses AngularFire internally.  Then, in your app's components, you can inject and use the service.  This allows you to easily mock out the service when unit testing your components.

But, I'm still not clear on how to go about testing the actual service itself.

As an example, say I have a `todo list` node in Firebase and I have a simple service that grabs all of the `todos`, like so:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  constructor(private af: AngularFire) { }

  getAll(): FirebaseListObservable<any[]> {
    return this.af.database.list('todos');
  }
}
```

How would you go about testing that this service does what you expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reaz recommended MockFirebase in his answer.  However, MockFirebase doesn't work with Firebase 3.  There is a library called firebase-mock, which appears to be developed by some of the same people as MockFirebase.  This augments MF, adding Firebase 3 support, however it [doesn't appear to play nicely with WebPack yet](https://github.com/soumak77/firebase-mock/issues/2).

### Here's what I ended up doing:

It occurred to me that `FirebaseListObservable` inherits from RXJS's `Observable`.  So, you can just mock out the AngularFire call to `list` and have it return your own Observable.

Some example code showing this in action:

`todos.service.spec.ts`

```js
let fixtureTodos = [
  { 'text': 'Get milk' },
  { 'text': 'Take out the trash' },
  { 'text': 'Get gas for the car' },
  { 'text': 'Pay parking ticket' },
  { 'text': 'Pick up dry cleaning' },
];
let angularFireDatabaseStub = { list: () => {} };
let mockTodos$ = Observable.of(fixtureTodos);

describe('TodosService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(angularFireDatabaseStub, 'list').and.returnValue(mockTodos$);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TodosService,
        { provide: AngularFireDatabase, useValue: angularFireDatabaseStub },
      ]
    });
  });

  it('#getAll', inject([TodosService], (service: TodosService) => {
    let todos$ = service.getAll();
    todos$.subscribe(todos => {
      expect(todos[0].text).toEqual(fixtureTodos[0].text);
      expect(todos[0]).toEqual(jasmine.any(Todo));
    });
  }));
});
```

`todos.service.ts`

```js
@Injectable()
export class TodosService {
  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getAll(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.db.list('todos').map(arr => {
      return arr.map(t => new Todo(t.text));
    });
  }
}
```

`todo.model.ts`

```js
export class Todo {
  constructor(public text: string) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is primarily opinion based and hence, I'm just putting my opinion here.

I would create a test node in Firebase having exactly the same model of my development database. So while writing the unit test, I would insert some data and retrieve them again to match with the data I inserted before.

Basically, Firebase stores data in a Json structure. So I would write some test Json todo entries. I won't mock the Firebase reference object or the connection as this is basically the third party software. I would make a real connection with Firebase while running the unit test, insert some data and retrieve them back and match with the data I've inserted before. That would be my approach.

**Update**

Yes, you've some valid concerns regarding continuous integration. Honestly, I haven't done something like this before with a team and a CI server. I can not guarantee a smooth experience.

While searching for a better solution I found [MockFirebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fingular) which might serve your purpose. You can have a look.

I would like to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21068672/3145960), where he suggested to keep the Firebase calls in a library. Though, this doesn't consider CI server.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  That's interesting.  So you would actually connect to Firebase in your test.  If I had the ability to run Firebase locally, I think I would be inclined to do it this way.  But, I'm hesitant to set up automated tests that rely on remote services.  I guess my hesitation is that it could lead to a less reliable CI experience.  I'm curious, have you done this in the past and had a smooth experience with it?  If so, were you doing it in a team environment with a continuous integration server?