# how to stop our mocked MongoDb in applicationContext for just 1 negative testCase?

Tags: java, mongodb, junit

How to simulate "DB down" condition for negative integration test of application ?

Have to write the negative integration test of application with mocked Db in context as follows:

```
    @Bean
public MongoDb mongoDb() throws URISyntaxException {
        return new MongoDb(new URI(String.format("mongodb://localhost:%s/", mongoDbPort)), databaseName);
    }
```

The class MongoDb being:

```
public class MongoDb {

    private final MongoClient mongo;
    private final String databaseName;

    public MongoDb(URI url, String databaseName) {
        log.debug("Mongodb url:" + url);
        mongo = new MongoClient(url.getHost(), url.getPort());
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdown() {
        log.debug("Tearing down mongo.");
        final MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase(databaseName);
        if (db != null) {
            db.drop();
        }
    }
}
```

How to simulate "DB down" condition here for negative test case (with same context bean)?

Tried Stopping the mongo in my testCase:
mongoDb.getMongo().dropDatabase(dbnameValue);
but it didn't raise any exception

Any clue is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an old post about using PowerMockito with MongoDB: [Unit testing with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413985/unit-testing-with-mongodb)

The API has changed but the way of mocking should still be usable.

```
MongoClient mongo = PowerMockito.mock(MongoClient.class);
PowerMockito.when(mongo.getDatabase("DBDownForTest")).doThrow(new MongoClientException("Test DB is down"));
```

This will only work if you are calling `getDatabase` with the argument `DBDownForTest`. Otherwise you will have to use `anyString()`.

Maybe you can even use Mockito without PowerMockito with current MongoDB versions.