# Unit tests for Ktor with KMongo

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, ktor, kmongo

How to make unit tests in `Ktor` with `KMongo`? How to mock database and make test on it? Let's say that I made simplest API like this:

```kotlin
private val client = KMongo.createClient().coroutine
private val database = client.getDatabase("dbName")
val people = database.getCollection<Person>()

suspend fun addPerson(person: Person): Boolean =
        people.insertOne(person).wasAcknowledged()

fun Route.addPersonRouting()
{
    route("/add")
    {
        post {
            if (addPerson(Person("Name", "Surname")))
            {
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, "ADDED")
            }
            else
            {
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, "NOT ADDED")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Test
fun `add person successfully`() = withTestApplication(
    {
        install(ContentNegotiation){ json() }
        routing { addPersonRouting() }  
    }
) {
    val c = handleRequest(HttpMethod.Post, "/add")
    assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, c.response.status())
    assertEquals("ADDED", c.response.content)
}
```

Now I can write a unit test but the problem is that database used for this test is not clean so before every test I have to clean it. I was thinking if there is any built-in database so the Test class can use it and with every run, it gives me a new clean DB. If it is possible I can modify Routing so it takes interface/database and in the application, I can pass normal database and to the tests, I can use test database. Probably something very similar is used in Android Room [`Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/testing-db#android).

*Would be nice if someone would show me step by step solution how to do this test with the clean mocked database without needing to clean it every time before running the test.*

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265927/13963150 you can find useful information about possible solutions for your problem.