# Spring Boot Mocking Mongodb setOnInsert

Tags: mongodb, mockito, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following MongoDB code that uses setonInsert

```
  public void populateRecords(Set<String> recNames) {
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = mongoHolder.getMongoTemplate();
    dbNames.forEach(recName -> {
      Update update = new Update()
          .setOnInsert(Fields.recName, recName)
          .setOnInsert(Fields.lastUpdated, LocalDateTime.MIN);
      mongoTemplate.update(RecordNameDocument.class)
          .apply(update)
          .upsert();
    });
  }
```

However Im not sure how to write a good Mock test for above code that uses setOnInsert
Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: It is better to use a `BulWrite` operation when you want to write/update documents created based upon data from a Java collection (instead using a for-loop now). Bulk write allows single database server call and a single result, and is efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mock the entire database class and collections

```
Mongo mongo = PowerMockito.mock(Mongo.class);
DB db = PowerMockito.mock(DB.class);
DBCollection dbCollection = PowerMockito.mock(DBCollection.class);

PowerMockito.when(mongo.getDB("foo")).thenReturn(db);
PowerMockito.when(db.getCollection("bar")).thenReturn(dbCollection);

MyService svc = new MyService(mongo); // Use some kind of dependency injection
svc.getObjectById(1);

PowerMockito.verify(dbCollection).findOne(new BasicDBObject("_id", 1));
```

as commented in this question:
[unit testing with mongo db and java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413985/unit-testing-with-mongodb)